# How to change the reference level of a meta-regression in metafor?

Tags: metafor

I'm running a univariate metaregression with the package metafor using the following code:

> resMeta <- rma(measure="IR",xi=xi, ti=ti, mods = ~ factor(pop)), data=metaAAS)
> resMeta
> confint(resMeta)

The levels of the moderator 'pop' are labelled as "0", "1", "2", and "3".
The problem is that the function automatically defines the first level ("0") of the moderator 'pop' as the reference level.

How do I change the reference for level "3"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `relevel()` function for that. So, for example:

```
resMeta <- rma(measure="IR",xi=xi, ti=ti, mods = ~ relevel(factor(pop), ref="3"), data=metaAAS)
resMeta
confint(resMeta)
```

to make level 3 the reference level.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Wolfgang. Thank you.
Just a small correction in the parenthesis after 'pop':
resMeta <- rma(measure="IR",xi=xi, ti=ti, mods = ~ relevel(factor(pop), ref="3"), data=metaAAS)